# Не получается сделать класс в Python

Tags: python

Задача была высчитать периметр шестиугольника с помощью класса с методом. Хотелось бы попробовать сделать более универсальную и практичную программу путём введения интерактива для людей, использующих программу. К сожалению, пришёл в тупик и очень бы хотел узнать причину и решение моей задачи.

Сам код:

```
class Hexagon:
    def __init__(self,l):
        self.lenght = l

    guest = input('Правильный ли шестиугольник? Да или Нет ')
    if guest == 'Да':
        lenght = input(int())
        def calculate_perimetr(self):
            return self.lenght * 6
    elif guest == 'Нет':
        list = []
        for i in range(6):
            rotate = input('Введите сторону ')
            list.append(rotate)
        print(list)

hexagon = Hexagon(1)
print(hexagon)
```

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, в чем заключается тупик и чего от этого кода требуется.

Comment: Не понимаю как вывести результат в конце программы.

Comment: Возможно, для начала стоит немного прочитать про синтаксис классов в питоне.

Comment: Действительно, перед тем, как задать вопрос, стоило бы хотя бы немного погуглить эту тему.

Comment: [Здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/obektno-orientirovannoe-programmirovanie-obshhee-predstavlenie.html) можно посмотреть несколько несложных примеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю следующее решение:

```py
class Hexagon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lenght = 0

    def calculate_perimetr_npr(self, params):
        self.lenght = sum(params)

    def calculate_perimetr_pr(self, l):
        self.lenght = l * 6

guest = input('Правильный ли шестиугольник? Да или Нет\n')
if guest == 'Да':
    hexagon = Hexagon()
    hexagon.calculate_perimetr_pr(int(input('Введите длину стороны\n')))
    print("Периметр шестиугольника равен ", hexagon.lenght)

elif guest == 'Нет':
    list = []
    for i in range(6):
        rotate = int(input('Введите сторону '))
        list.append(rotate)
    hexagon = Hexagon()
    hexagon.calculate_perimetr_npr(list)
    print("Периметр шестиугольника равен ", hexagon.lenght)
```

Этот код далёк от совершенства, т.к. писался абсолютно "на скорую руку".

Чтобы не вдаваться в критику кода в вопросе, автору вопроса совет: при получении задания на определённую тему стоит разобраться в ней, прежде чем писать какой-либо код. Если тема ООП нова для Вас, следует почитать, что такое классы, зачем нужны и как с их помощью реализовать то или иное ПО. И, конечно же, ознакомиться с синтаксисом языка, на котором планируете реализовывать.

И ещё небольшое дополнение о тексте вопроса: универсальность и практичность программы не обеспечиваются включением в класс диалога с конечным пользователем программы. Пользователем класса является программист и "диалог" с ним осуществляется посредством правильного именования классов, методов и аргументов, а также грамотного комментирования кода. А функция вывода информации на экран для пользователя созданной программы либо выносится в отдельный класс (в более сложном ПО), либо прописывается в основном теле программы (в учебных программах, как Ваша).

Answer (score 0):

> hexagon = Hexagon(1)
>
> print(hexagon)

Добавьте метод `__str__()` для того способа вывода, который вы используете

```
class Hexagon(......):
    ....

    def __str__(self):
        return <То что дожно быть выведено> 
        # Например: return "Hexagon with length %d" % self.length
```

---

[Классы в Python (https://python-scripts.com/python-class)](https://python-scripts.com/python-class)